# Javascript string to array/dictionary

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, string, list

How can i convert a string like this:

```
"{u'value': {u'username': u'testeuser', u'status': 1,
 u'firstName': u'a', u'lastName': u'a', u'gender': u'a',
 u'date': u'2013-03-06T09:01:27.939007',
 u'id': u'b1dab21bef3f3fd050d7c2f3e8006045'},
 u'key': u'2013-03-06T09:01:27.939007'}"
```

to something like a list that i can find info like `data['value']` or `data['username']` ?

Comment: i've tried to use substr and split methods but i think its not a widespread solution.

Comment: "something like a list" you are probably looking for associative arrays

Comment: It looks a bit like a JS object literal, but those `u'` delimiters disturb it. How did you got that?

Comment: @Bergi It is stringifying of Python dictionary (wrong approach of serialization).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string looks like you've wrongly serialized your dictionary. To pass data (e.g. dictionary, list, etc) to the client side you need to serialize it in **JSON** format.

In order to do this in your Python code you should use [`json.dumps(dict)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) from `json` package, while in the client side you need to apply [`JSON.parse(data)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to load the data back.

Comment: with some modifications, i could send the serialized object correctly using the method you said! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

- use eval()
- like, I need to convert string of list-dict to list
- by using `eval("[{'range_type': '__to', 'value': '710'}, {'range_type': '__from', 'value': '700'}]")` i got this: `[{'range_type': '__to', 'value': '710'}, {'range_type': '__from', 'value': '700'}]`